# How to I limit the x and y axes with tmap in r

Tags: r, sp, sf, ggmap

I have made this plot with the following code:

```
library(tmap)    
tm_shape(RH2) +
      tm_fill(col="AREAL") +
      tm_borders()
```

[image]

But there is a dot on the far right (an island) which I don't understand why it is there. Is there a way to limit the plot to avoid all the white spaces? like `coord_fixed(xlim=c(7, 12), ylim=c(52, 58))` in ggmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you read the help for `tm_shape`? It gives the following parameter:

```
bbox: bounding box. One of the following:

        • A bounding box (an ‘sf’ bbox object, see ‘st_bbox’, a 2
          by 2 matrix (used by the ‘sp’ package), or an ‘Extent’
          object used by the ‘raster’ package).
```

Its in map units rather than lat-long, so with the `World` data from the help you can do:

```
tm_shape(World, bbox=tmaptools::bb(matrix(c(0,0,2000000,2000000),2,2))) +tm_polygons()
```

Comment: @ Thanks spacedman. I will look at it tomorrow when I have my computer. But what is your take on sp vs sf objects?

Comment: Use `sf` whenever possible.

Comment: @ Spacedman: How does one convert lon-lat units to map units?

Comment: Its the same coordinates as the thing you have in the `tm_shape` function. If this is a thing in lat-long coordinates, then the map coordinates are also lat-long coordinates. But if you are working with maps in projected coordinates then you use those. see `sp::spTransform` or `sf:st_transform` for more.

Comment: @ Spacedman:  Actually I don't think I need transforming. If I look at the "dots" geometry object and print it, the ``sf object`` prints the numbers I need for making the bbox. That is ``mysf_object$geometry[row_num]``. But how can I get the bbox numbers for the main plot?

Comment: `st_bbox(mysf_object$geometry[-row_num])` should get the bbox for all rows *except* (because of the minus sign) the specified row number.