# Legend color scale problem with tmap for island

Tags: r, sp, sf, ggmap

```
Bornholm_data <- geo_RH %>% 
  filter(KOMNAVN=="Bornholm") 



tm_shape(geo_RH) +
  tm_fill(col="Befolkning") +
  tm_borders()  



mainland <-  tm_shape(mainland_data, projection = 0) + 
  tm_fill(col="AREAL") +
  tm_polygons() + 
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)   


Bornholm_map   <-  tm_shape(Bornholm_data) + 
  tm_fill(col="AREAL") +
  tm_polygons() + 
  tm_layout(title = "Bornholm", frame = TRUE, bg.color = NA, 
            title.position = c("RIGHT", "TOP"))


mainland 
print(Bornholm_map, vp = viewport(x = 0.8, y = 0.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.2))
```

[image]

I know that the color on the map is not correct because a simple plot produces this which is the reality [image]

Comment: In short, the problem here is that the Bornholm map is an independent map of a single row of the data and so is using a scale of its own, and so its unrelated to the scale for the larger map.

Comment: @ Spacedman: Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way. Instead of taking one element out of the data and making a map with it, make two maps with all the data, but the inset map is cropped to the element you want to focus on. Here's an example using the `data(World)` dataset you get with `tmap`:

Make a world map using `pop_est` for the fill colour:

```
> world = tm_shape(World) + tm_fill("pop_est")
```

India is the 74th row:

```
> World$name[74]
[1] India
177 Levels: Afghanistan Albania Algeria Angola Antarctica Argentina ... Zimbabwe
```

Make an India map with no legend (so we don't get a tiny legend in our inset map). I use the `bbox=` argument to set the bounds to the box that contains India:

```
> india = tm_shape(World, bbox=st_bbox(World[74,])) + 
      tm_fill("pop_est", legend.show=FALSE)
```

Set a viewport and combine the world and india:

```
> vp = viewport(.3,.3,.2,.2)
> world
> print(india, vp=vp)
```

[image]

Worst cartography ever, but shows that India is coloured according to the main legend.

Comment: @ Spacedman: So the complete solution actually also needs to limit the x and y axis in the original "plot" as you explained here [link] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310485/how-to-i-limit-the-x-and-y-axes-with-tmap-in-r). Why is tmap better than ggplot? Will this issue be easier to solve with ggplot?