# Showing a study area in a map

Tags: coordinate-system, r, mapping

I have my study area as a raster file and I want to show it on a much bigger map in R. I can show it using the « plot » of the raster file but at this point, I can’t see it inside a map. Is there any way to do this in R?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/310485/8104

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing the outline of your study area to a vector (i.e., polygon), then use something like:

```
plot(raster)
plot(vector, add=TRUE)
```